# Find conditions in which the function $F$ has a continuously differentiable inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Let $f\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be an entire non constant function. We consider its values on the real line. The function $f$ has infinitely many real zeros and there is infinitely many real solutions to the equation $f(s)=w$ for any real number $w$. Here the set of those real $s$ is a discrete set. The same properties holds true for all the $k^{th}$ derivatives of $f$.

Let
$$F:U⊂ℝ^{r+1}→ℝ^{r+1}$$
$$(s₁,s₂,...,s_{r},s_{r+1})→F(s₁,s₂,...,s_{r},s_{r+1})=(f′(s₁),f′′(s₂),f′′′(s₃),.....,f^{(r)}(s_{r}),f^{(r+1)}(s_{r+1}))$$ be a continuously differentiable function defined from an open set $U⊂ℝ^{r+1}$ into $ℝ^{r+1}$.

My **question** is : Find sufficient and necessary conditions in which the function $F$ has a continuously differentiable inverse function defined in some neighborhoods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobian of $F$ is
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{r+1}f^{(i+1)}(s_i).
$$
A sufficient condition for the existence of $F^{-1}$ in a neighborhood of $(s_1,\dots,s_{r+1})$ is $f^{(i+1)}(s_i)\ne0$, $1\le i\le r+1$. Since
$$
F^{-1}(t_1,\dots,t_{r+1})=\bigl((f^{(i)})^{-1}(t_i)\bigr)_{i=1}^{r+1},
$$
it is also necessary for $F^{-1}$ to be $C^1$.